# My Python linear regression has incomplete line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot a linear regression. But the line is incomeplete. Below is my Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

features = [[2],[4],[8],[5]]
labels = [320, 610, 1190, 726]

plt.scatter(features,labels,color="black")
plt.xlabel("Number of room")
plt.ylabel('price')

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf=clf.fit(features,labels)
result = clf.predict([[11],[9]])

plt.plot([[11],[9]], result, color='blue', linewidth=3)

print(result)
plt.show()
```

And the picture of the plot is given below:
[image]

From the picture, you can see that the line is incomplete. Please help me to solve this problem. Make the line complete with all the other values.

Comment: I guess, `plt.plot([[11],[9]]` -> `plt.plot([[11],[2]]`?

Comment: `[[11],[9]]`: you may want to expand this to the actual range you want to plot. I guess you can just use `[2, 11]` (1-dimensional).